# python for image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

[Output of prewitt filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOXHN.png)

I tried to extract the circular features in the image and I couldn't get a decent result.`

```
# Detect different radii
hough_radii = np.arange(10, 30, 2)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)

centers = []
accums = []
radii = []


for radius, h in zip(hough_radii, hough_res):
    # For each radius, extract two circles
    peaks = peak_local_max(h, num_peaks=2)
    centers.extend(peaks)
    accums.extend(h[peaks[:, 0], peaks[:, 1]])
    radii.extend([radius, radius])

# Draw the most prominent circles
#image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) #color.gray2rgb(image)
image = color.gray2rgb(image)
for idx in np.argsort(accums)[::-1][:5]:
    center_x, center_y = centers[idx]
    radius = radii[idx]
    cx, cy = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius)
    image[cy, cx] = (220, 20, 20)
out2 = img_as_uint(image[cy, cx])
plt.imshow(out2)
```

`

Comment: Below is my algorithm
hough_radii = np.arange(10, 30, 2)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)
centers = []
accums = []
radii = []
for radius, h in zip(hough_radii, hough_res):
    peaks = peak_local_max(h, num_peaks=2)
    centers.extend(peaks)
    accums.extend(h[peaks[:, 0], peaks[:, 1]])
    radii.extend([radius, radius])

image = color.gray2rgb(image)
for idx in np.argsort(accums)[::-1][:5]:
    center_x, center_y = centers[idx]
    radius = radii[idx]
    cx, cy = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius)
    image[cy, cx] = (220, 20, 20)

Comment: Please add your code properly formatted to the question via the `edit` button!

Comment: @nlsdfnbch I tried to use the edit botton but couldn't get through it
if you don't mind, check your twitter and follow back.

Comment: @nlsdfnbch, I have uploaded the code.
Looking forward to your correction.